# Envio correo Gmail con Laravel 5.4 , Class 'App\Mail\' not found

Tags: laravel, phpmailer

tengo configurado el correo de gmail para envió de mensajes , en localhost funciona todo bien, pero cuando lo subo al servidor no me encuentra la clase `Correo` (que es la que estoy usando).

esto es el extracto de mi controlador

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Mail;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Reserva;
use App\Mail\Correo;

 $data = Reserva::all()->last(); //Reserva es un modelo, 
 Mail::to($data->correo,$data->nombre)
        ->send(new Correo($data)); //acá siempre me da el error
```

el mail `Correo` es el siguiente

```
namespace App\Mail;

use App\Reserva;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class Correo extends Mailable{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $reserva;

    public function __construct(Reserva $reserva) {
                $this->reserva = $reserva;
    }

    public function build()        {
        return $this->view('email.email');
    }
}
```

Lo que no entiendo es que en local funciona todo bien, el error que siempre me sale es

```
 Class 'App\Mail\Correo' not found
```

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de que puede estar pasando?
de antemano muchisimas gracias

Comment: Revisaste por las dudas mediante FTP (o lo que sea) que el archivo `Correo` se haya subido correctamente? Por otro lado, `use Mail` debería ser `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail`.

Comment: Si, el archivo si esta, cambiaré 'use' y veré que sucede

Comment: no, lo cambié y sigue sin encontrar el archivo.. ¿la carpeta `mail` debe estar en `app/mail` o debería estar en la carpeta `public` (quizás por eso no la encuentra...?

Comment: En `app\Mail` ojo con las mayúsculas, creería que no da lo mismo. Por ahí en local estás trabajando desde Windows (que es case insensitive) y al subir el contenido a un server con Linux (que es case sensitive) aparecen los problemas.